# Searching for Scanners/MFDs with Native 64-bit TWAIN Drivers

Tags: drivers, 64-bit, 32-bit, scanner, twain

I’ve been searching for companies that developed native 64-bit TWAIN drivers for their scanners, but I seem to only find drivers that work with WoW (I’m assuming those drivers are 32-bit). Is development of native 64-bit TWAIN drivers uncommon? Other than searching for drivers of various scanners, is there a centralized source where I could find this? This is anecdotal, but tech support people for scanner manufactures don’t seem to understand the difference between an OS’s bit version and the driver’s bit version. So I’m skeptical of the information they’re giving me.

[image: Drivers for scanner]

Comment: Is it even possible to use 32-bit TWAIN drivers on a 64-bit system? (I tried with absolutely no success.)

Comment: I thought that’s what Windows on Windows 64 does. Takes an application developed for a 32-bit system and allows it to run on a 64-bit system. I put a picture in my question of a driver description for Canon scanner they’re all WoW on the 64-bit systems.

Comment: Applications, yes. Printer drivers, apparently yes (the usermode ones – there's no WoW for kernel mode drivers). But I couldn't get my 32-bit "WinXP" scanner driver to install _at all_; I still use a VM.